# Capacitor between boost and sw pin

Tags: capacitor, buck, component-failure

I want to use [THis](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3470fd.pdf) buck regulator and i was wondring what is the function of the capacitor between the Boost and the SW pin ? 
And What happen if i choose to not add this capacitor ?

Comment: (1) see page 6 and page 8. It's a charge pump. (2) The high side switch doesn't turn on fully, wasting power and overheating.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the function of the capacitor between the Boost and the SW pin ?

It pumps the boosted voltage.

> And What happen if i choose to not add this capacitor ?

The boost function won't work.

Comment: But the buck regulator can still work without the boost function ?

Comment: No. The "boost" function in this case refers to the extra voltage required to drive the NPN switching transistor into full conduction.